# AdaboostR2 (Drucker, 1997) (boosting for regression) r code

Tags: r, root

I'm searching for a package or a way to use the algorithm Adaboost.R2 (adaboost for regression) in R. I can use it in ROOT and change my loss function in "quadratic" and I want to get the same thing in R. Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried searching rseek.org?

Comment: Yes, of course! There are some packages like **ada** and **gbm** but if I understand well they don't use the Algorithm that I want. ( AdaBoost.R2 (Drucker, 1997))

Comment: Ah ok. You are not looking for shapira's adaboost algorithm that is in `gbm`? Maybe it is good to add that to your question to avoid confusion.